# System.IO.FileNotFoundException error despite the file existing

Tags: c#, error-handling

The error I get is:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

It occurs despite the file existing.

Here's the code

```cs
Config config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Config>(File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\config\\config.json")));

using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\config\\config.json"))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    Config config1 = (Config)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(Config));
}
```

Comment: to verify that you have the correct file name, Console log the path.

Console.WriteLine(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\config\\config.json"));
Console.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\config\\config.json");

and verify in file explorer that the file indeed exist.

Comment: _"despite the file existing"_ -- despite _what_ file existing? Take a look at the exception message. It's not complaining about the `config.json` file. It's complaining about the `System.Security.Permissions` assembly file. Check your references for the project and make sure you're using the right assembly.

Comment: When you have found out the reason why an **assembly** is missing, remove that `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`. You're already using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`, maybe assign the path combined with that to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio. Right click on file and click properties. Set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always".

Comment: And what file do you think the OP should change the properties for? The message clearly indicates that what's missing is an _assembly_. There won't be a file in the project for that assembly to change the properties for.